# How should I return a hash from a module?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Please excuse my english if it's not perfect.

I have a controller where I set the data for few charts. In this methods, I have a block that I use in several methods, so I created a module to put this code and use it in the methods where I need it (should I do this or just create a method in my controller?).

The problem is that the hash return in my module is nil in my controller (but not in my module).

Could you please tell me where is my mistake?
I call the method from my module in just after `if params[:checked] == 'true'`

**Controller:**

```
module Admin
  class AdminController < ApplicationController
    include WeeklyCharts #=> I include my module

    def signup_stats(start_date, end_date)

      customer_signup_chart = {
        type: 'line',
        data: [],
        label: 'New customer registrations'
      }

      freelance_signup_chart = {
        type: 'line',
        data: [],
        label: 'New freelance registrations'
      }

      users = User
        .where('created_at > :start_date AND created_at < :end_date',
          start_date: start_date.beginning_of_day,
          end_date: end_date.end_of_day)
        .select(:created_at, :typology)

      if params[:checked] == 'true'
        set_datasets_labels(start_date, end_date) #=> Method in my module
        users = users.group_by_week(week_start: start_date.strftime('%a').downcase.to_sym, format: '%j %y') { |u| u.created_at }

        loop do
          client_signup_chart[:data] << (users[start_date.to_date.strftime('%j %y')] ? users[start_date.to_date.strftime('%j %y')].count {|u| u.typology == 'customer'} : 0)
          presta_signup_chart[:data] << (users[start_date.to_date.strftime('%j %y')] ? users[start_date.to_date.strftime('%j %y')].count {|u| u.typology == 'freelance'} : 0)
          start_date += 1.week
          break if start_date > end_date
        end

      else
        datasets = { labels: (start_date.to_datetime..end_date.to_datetime).map {|date| I18n.l(date, format: :date)}}
        users =  users.group_by { |u| u.created_at.to_date }

        loop do
          client_signup_chart[:data] << (users[start_date.to_date] ? users[start_date.to_date].count {|u| u.typology == 'customer'} : 0)
          presta_signup_chart[:data] << (users[start_date.to_date] ? users[start_date.to_date].count {|u| u.typology == 'freelance'} : 0)
          start_date += 1.day
          break if start_date > end_date
        end
      end

      datasets[:charts] = [customer_signup_chart, freelance_signup_chart] #=> undefined method `[]=' for nil:NilClass
      datasets
    end
  end
end
```

**My module:**

```
module WeeklyCharts

    def set_datasets_labels(start_date, end_date)
        start_day = start_date.strftime('%A').downcase.to_sym
        datasets = { labels: (start_date.to_datetime..end_date.to_datetime).map {|date| date.beginning_of_week(start_day = start_day).strftime("From %d/%m to #{date.end_of_week(start_day = start_day).strftime('%d/%m')}")}.uniq}
        datasets[:labels][0] = "From #{start_date.strftime('%d/%m')} to #{start_date.end_of_week(start_day = start_day).strftime('%d/%m')}"
        datasets[:labels][-1] = "From #{end_date.beginning_of_week(start_day = start_day).strftime('%d/%m')} to #{end_date.strftime('%d/%m')}"

        datasets
    end

end
```

**The error returned:**

```
datasets[:charts] = [customer_signup_chart, freelance_signup_chart]
#=> undefined method `[]=' for nil:NilClass
```

Also, I can `p datasets` from the module, it's only in my controller that it's `nil`

If you need more details please ask to me.

Comment: You call the method, but you don't assign the result to anywhere. Try `datasets = set_datasets_labels(start_date, end_date)`.

Comment: Erk, you're right @ndn, thank you. Can you create an answer that I can validate?

Comment: If by "validate" you mean "check if it works", just replace the line where you currently have `set_datasets_labels(start_date, end_date)` with `datasets = set_datasets_labels(start_date, end_date)`.

Comment: Oh no, I mean, create an answer to the topic that I can mark as having solved the problem. :) Your solution works perfectly

Comment: I'll skip this one. (: You can post an answer to your own question and accept it.